# Телеграмм бот авито парсер: "org.jsoup.HttpStatusException:HTTP error fetching URL. status = 403"

Tags: java, telegram-bot, jsoup

Написал простенького бота на java jsoup, который парсит авито, запускаю на локально все ок. Выложил его на vps с первого же коннекта выдает ошибку, очень редко все таки получается законектиться. В чем проблема, в ip?
Коннект не частый, раз в 3 сек.

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException:HTTP error fetching URL. status = 403
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403 Возможно, авито не нравится ip

Comment: @gil9red 
попробовал proxy, продолжение темы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183790/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-proxy-java

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Трассу стека тоже нужно было оставить она дает дополнительную информацию

Comment: просто это консоль vps, не получается скопировать) приходится руками писать)

Comment: Оно же как-то выводится, а значит это можно извлечь :) Если это на сайте, то через инспектора (обычно он на F12), а там уже посмотреть DOM страницы и вытащить из тегов

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает , что Авито не нравятся парсеры, что его смущают заголовки клиента, с которого идёт запрос, что ему могут не нравится ваши куки или вообще их отсутствие. Также его может смущать отсутствие поддержки js. Из всего этого я полагаю, что то делает вывод, что вы клиент не самый нужный и отказывает вам в ответе

Comment: Я бы вам предложил еще перехватить тело ответа запроса ( с 403 статусом оно тоже вполне себе может быть) скорее всего там он просит ввести вас капчу

Comment: Да и вообще.У них апи есть https://api.avito.ru/docs/api.html

Comment: @Михаил Ребров просто с локального компьютера 100 из 100 проходят)заголовки же одни и те же?на локальном и на vps?за api спасибо.

Comment: @aptu.lu, ну раз на локальном все в порядке - используйте прокси

Comment: @aptu.lu, либо хороший платный, либо храните библиотеку бесплатных и отмечайте по каким ip запросы не проходят и не используйте их в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

Я много раз пытался соединиться с указанным хостом используя Curl (php) с опцией включенного прокси. И заголовки разные и прочее, ничего не помогало.
Однако, простейшая конструкция решила вопрос (уж не знаю, что они там проверяют)

```
    $aContext = array(
         'http' => array(
             'proxy' => 'tcp://'.PROXY_ADR,
             'request_fulluri' => true,
          ),
    );
    $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
    $sFile = file_get_contents("https://avito.ru", False, $cxContext);
    echo $sFile;
```