# Проблема при подключении к прокси: "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Tags: java, proxy

купил proxy для парсинга авито с логином и паролем

```
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", ipProxy);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", portProxy);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", login);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", password);
```

при попытке подключиться следующая ошибка, в чем может быть проблема? еще есть порт socks, как его использовать? нужен ли он?

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:169)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:732)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)
    at parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:43)
    at bot.ThreadAvitoParser.run(ThreadAvitoParser.java:23)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Проблема с самой прокси... скорее всего в запрос нужно в добавлять какой-то HTTP заголовок, например с каким-то токеном, чтобы прокси его приняла и отправила к целевому сайту. Посмотрите, например, мануалы по прокси на сайте где вы ее брали

Comment: А если использовать эту прокси не из кода а с браузером, работает?

Comment: @Alexey R. пробовал через postman, та же ошибка, куда только логин и пароль не писал, щас написал поставщику, жду ответа